# Issuing fresh passport in India when birthdate is wrong in some documents

Tags: india, passports, indian-citizens

One of my friend having a problem in issuing new passport in India. The problem is of his birthdate, here's what he's told me.

He was born in October 1988, after his completion of 10th std. (S.S.C.) in year of 2004, his birthdate have been changed by mistake to October 1989, *he became one year younger* by his School Leaving Certificate (in short call as LC). But however he applied for all the valid documents on basis of his birth certificate (which contains the correct date). So he has the following documents which having his correct birthdate (which he wants) are,

- Birth certificate
- PAN Card
- Election Card
- UDID (Aadhar) Card
- Driving Licence

these all documents having correct birthdate except LC, so in all *educational* documents contains incorrect (wrong) date.

Now he get chance to visit to US, so he applied for passport where his application got rejected on basic of difference of dates on the LC and other (above) documents.

He tried for,

- Affidavit (but he couldn't find a proper affidavit source for this, there's one available on http://passportindia.gov.in/ is [this](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/AnnexureA.pdf) but that's for illiterate person - and he's not a illiterate person.)

Is there a way that, he would ensure that he would get the passport?

He don't want incorrect date on his passport.

Does he need to do an affidavit, if Yes, please link me to the proper format for that. It would be great if you will share a valid source for that.

Any other possible solutions?

He said that, I'm correct at my place and I don't want to do anything wrong.

---

*Ask me if you want more information on this.*

Comment: The obvious solution would be to have the LC corrected and reissued.

Comment: Why dont you ask the experts?
http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqCallCentre

Comment: @pal4life, Yes I could. But I guess they want give answer of such problem. I am guessing from here I would reach to wide range of people who might fall into same situation or some similar? In my knowledge SE would always helpful when you in real trouble.

Comment: One of these days somebody's going to claim a relavisitic time effect causes dates to not match elapsed time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submitting educational certificates is not essential for getting a passport. I checked [on the Government of India website for passports](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/docAdvisor/attachmentAdvFresh)  and it looks like you can use the birth certificate as proof of date of birth and Aadhar Card as proof of address. For non-ECR, you could use 12th class or college certificate which generally do not mention date of birth. Alternately, the income tax return can also be used if available.

However, I will recommend that your friend should contact the school and board to try and get the certificated corrected. You may be able to get the passport now, but this discrepancy will keep creating problems. Also, contact a good notary or lawyer to get an affidavit made which will be useful while you are working on getting the educational certificates re-issued with correct birth date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nikhil. He'd already tried with as per the link on the website, as I've suggested to him. But at PSK their not allowing this. They must ask for LC.

Comment: I have gone through the same. It is doable, but will take about 2 months to do.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to find a workaround this will get you into an even bigger mess.

I understand how these situations come to be in the first place but the correct procedure to fix this is to either get an affidavit which suggests that the date on the School Leaving Certificate is incorrect or get the School Leaving Certificate fixed.

Either way, not doing this at this point of time will lead to more problems in the future due to incorrect dates on some documents. I know it's difficult to get the School Leaving Certificate revised, so you should **get a Notarized Affidavit to showcase that the person on the School Leaving Certificate is indeed you**.

But consider this a temporary solution, the permanent solution would be to contact CBSE or ICSE and get the school leaving certificate revised.

Comment: Have you ever seen such a case when a date changed in board (my friend was in Gujarat Board) which changed 8 years back and now the board allowed to change his date in all the certificates? If yes so, do you know the exact procedure for that?

Comment: @Hemang I haven't seen a case personally, but a notarized affidavit should help you get both jobs done. You will have to visit the board office and gather more information though.

Comment: As I've included in my question, my friend already tried for that, but the said affidavit is for illiterate person. He's not a illiterate, he is double graduated from reputed university.

Comment: @Hemang I'm not talking about that specific affidavit. I'm talking about a special affidavit which notaries commonly use for such disputed matters. If you contact the notary you will be able to obtain the affidavit. These issues are relatively common, most commonly with errors in name.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, It would be a great help for me, if you find a demo affidavit for this? He tried with that, where everyone (by mean, notary person) was asking for a sample of such affidavit.

Comment: One more question, I read on FAQ site for passport, even if I'll get a passport based on the affidavit, after 10 (ten) years my passport will be expire and I'll need to make reissue process, would it create the problem same as today?

Comment: @Hemang I'm not sure where you can find a format (try talking to a lawyer, they can usually customize one for you) but you can then use the affidavit to get the certificate revised as well.